# How to disable browser's back button after logout in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to disable browser's back button after login in asp.net. I tried to put javascript  like window.history.forward(1) function or Response.Cache function. That coding works in my web application. But back button is not disabled. How to do that?

Comment: Even if this was possible, your users would HATE you for doing it.

Comment: and why do your want to do it. Any requirement

Answer (score 0):

We cannot disable browser back button.You can try below code, it may help:-

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

 <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">

 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Back history is maintained by browser, you will need to close the window.

Comment: Back history is accessible however using JS (window.history).

Comment: Not after closing the window.

Comment: No but he doesn't want to close the window. He wants to disable the back button after somebody logs in so that they can't try and go back to the login page, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just redirect logged in user to your desired page like a user dashboard or something when they go back to your login page? You could use sessions to determine logged in users.